# please help me, don't read the file "mem.dat"

Tags: file, memory, vhdl

Description memory . VHDL

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Memory is 
    generic(file_name: string:= "MEM.dat");
port (addr: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        data: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        rd: in std_logic;
        ld: in std_logic);
end Memory;

architecture Memory of Memory is
type t_rom_data is array (15 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
type rom_file_type is file of character;
file rom_file: rom_file_type;
signal rom_data: t_rom_data;
begin   
    process(addr,rd)
    variable i: natural;
    begin
        if rd = '1' then
            i := conv_integer(addr);
            data <= rom_data(i) after 5ns;
        else 
            data <= (others => 'Z');
        end if;
    end process;

    process(ld)
    variable c: character;
    begin
        if ld='1' then  file_open(rom_file,file_name,read_mode);
            for i in 0 to 15 loop
                for b in 7 downto 0 loop
                    c:='U';
                    if not(endfile(rom_file)) then  read(rom_file,c);
                        while not(endfile(rom_file)) and c/='0' and c/='1' and c/='Z' and c/='W'
                        and c/='L' and c/='H' and c/='-' and c/='X' and c/='U' loop
                            read(rom_file,c);
                        end loop;                   
                    end if; 

                    if c='0' then rom_data(i)(b) <= '0';
                    elsif c='1' then rom_data(i)(b) <='1';
                    elsif c='Z' then rom_data(i)(b) <='Z';
                    elsif c='W' then rom_data(i)(b) <='W';
                    elsif c='L' then rom_data(i)(b) <='L';
                    elsif c='H' then rom_data(i)(b) <='H';
                    elsif c='-' then rom_data(i)(b) <='-';
                    elsif c='X' then rom_data(i)(b) <='X';
                    else rom_data(i)(b) <='U';
                    end if;

                end loop;
            end loop;
            file_close(rom_file); 
        end if;`enter code here`
    end process;
end Memory;
```

error is:
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[15][7]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[15][6]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[15][5]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[15][4]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[15][3]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[15][2]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[15][1]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[15][0]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[14][7]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[14][6]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)
Warning (10873): Using initial value X (don't care) for net "rom_data[14][5]" at MEMORY.vhd(17)

file "mem.dat" is in the same directory as the project. I work in quartus

Comment: This is for simulation, not synthesis, right?

Comment: I do not know how to read the file using Altera Quartus , this is result of compilation

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be about how to initialise a ROM with data from file, for synthesis. If that is the case, then obviously running a process to load the data into memory (which requires the file to be readable at run time) is not going to work.

What you can do, however, is declare the memory - not as a `SIGNAL` but as a `CONSTANT` and the declaration must have an initialiser clause; this is allowed to call a function. And because the initialiser is evaluated during synthesis, it can open, read and close files.

An example might look like

```
type t_rom_data is array (15 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

function init_rom return t_rom_data is
   type rom_file_type is file of character;
   file rom_file: rom_file_type;
   variable temp : t_rom_data;
begin
   file_open(rom_file,file_name,read_mode);
   for i in 0 to 15 loop
      ...
      temp(i) := ...
   end loop;
   file_close(rom_file); 
   return temp;
end init_rom;

constant rom_data: t_rom_data := init_rom;
```

with the ROM read process as you have written it.